# Cannot write razor code in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, session-variables

I am going crazy searching for it, but I can,t find any solution to my problem. 
All I want is to set Session in razor with value of javascript variable.

My Code is:

```
  function SetParameter() {
    var OrderShipmentInd = "";
    if ($("#rdoOrd").attr("checked") == "checked")
        OrderShipmentInd = "O";
    else
        OrderShipmentInd = "S";

    @Session["OrderShipmentInd"] = OrderShipmentInd;
}
```

I get error "Conditional Compilation is turned off". when I use /*@("@cc_on @")*/ to remove this error, it does not work. my page does not renders.

Please anyone help, how to do this. Does this world has any experts?

Comment: (Assuming this is client side js), you will need to Post or Ajax the `OrderShipmentInd` back to the server in order to store it in `Session`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

Session is run on the **server**, but javascript is run on **client**. To get that value into a session, you should use either an ajax get/post into a controller action, or post the whole into a controller/action and add it there.

e.g.

**Javascript**:

```
function SetParameter() {
    var OrderShipmentInd = "";
    if ($("#rdoOrd").attr("checked") == "checked")
        OrderShipmentInd = "O";
    else
        OrderShipmentInd = "S";

    $.get ('/OrderShipment', { order: OrderShipmentInd });
}
```

**MVC Action**:

```
public ActionResult OrderShipment(string order)
{
      @Session["OrderShipmentInd"] = order;
      //..
}
```